# Base64 encode binary uploaded data on the AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, encoding, base64

I've been trying to Base64 encode image data from the user (in this case a trusted admin) in order to skip as many calls to the BlobStore as I possibly can. Every time I attempt to encode it, I recieve an error saying:

```
Error uploading image: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've googled the error (the less significant parts) and found that it may have something to do with Unicode (?). The template portion is just a basic upload form, while the handler contains the following code:

```
  def post(self,id):
    logging.info("ImagestoreHandler#post %s", self.request.path)
    fileupload = self.request.POST.get("file",None)
    if fileupload is None : return self.error(400)

    content_type = fileupload.type or getContentType( fileupload.filename )
    if content_type is None: 
      self.error(400)
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
      self.response.out.write( "Unsupported image type: " + fileupload.filename )
      return
    logging.debug( "File upload: %s, mime type: %s", fileupload.filename, content_type )

    try:
      (img_name, img_url) = self._store_image(
        fileupload.filename, fileupload.file, content_type )
      self.response.headers['Location'] = img_url
      ex=None
    except Exception, err:
      logging.exception( "Error while storing image" )
      self.error(400)
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
      self.response.out.write("Error uploading image: " + str(err))
      return
    #self.redirect(urlBase % img.key() )  #dummy redirect is acceptable for non-AJAX clients,
    # location header should be acceptable for true REST clients, however AJAX requests 
    # might not be able to access the location header so we'll write a 200 response with 
    # the new URL in the response body:

    acceptType = self.request.accept.best_match( listRenderers.keys() )
    out = self.response.out
    if acceptType == 'application/json':
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      out.write( '{"name":"%s","href":"%s"}' % ( img_name, img_url ) )
    elif re.search( 'html|xml', acceptType ):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
      out.write( '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % ( img_url, img_name) )

  def _store_image(self, name, file, content_type):
    """POST handler delegates to this method for actual image storage; as
    a result, alternate implementation may easily override the storage
    mechanism without rewriting the same content-type handling. 

    This method returns a tuple of file name and image URL."""

    img_enc = base64.b64encode(file.read())
    img_enc_struct = "data:%s;base64,%s" % (content_type, img_enc)

    img = Image( name=name, data=img_enc_struct )
    img.put()
    logging.info("Saved image to key %s", img.key() ) 
    return ( str(img.name), img.key() )
```

My image model:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Image(db.Model):

  name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  data = db.TextProperty(required=True)
  created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  owner = db.UserProperty(auto_current_user_add=True)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. This code, minus my image encoding in _store_image, comes from the blooger branch of gvdent [here](http://github.com/gvdent/bloog).

Comment: can you show your image model ?

Comment: I updated it to include the image model as well.

Comment: The error doesn't have anything to do with Unicode; Python is trying to encode your binary data as a string and assumes it's ASCII, then chokes on bytes that are > 127 because they're not valid ASCII.  It's true that this error is usually encountered when dealing with utf-8 data (which also uses the 8th bit), but it's not exclusive to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your store image code could be like this....

```
img = Image( name=name, data=file.read() )
img.put()
return ( str(img.name), img.key() )
```

doing base64encode of binary data may increase the size of data itself and increase the cpu encoding and decoding time.

and Blobstore uses the same storage sturcuture as datastore, so it is just making easier to 
use file upload store download.